# Hide/Show divs based on check box selection

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show / hide divs based on check box selection.

here is the scenario,

- I have two check box in a div named *decider*,
- selecting check box one should show Div box-one
- selecting check box two should show Div box-two

Once someone has made the selection, i want the *decider* div to hide. I am not being able to make this work

```js
$(function() {
 $('.decider').removeClass('hide');
 $('.box-one').addClass('hide');
    
 $("#optionTwo").click(function() {
     $('#optionOne').attr("checked",false);
 });

 $("#optionOne").click(function() {
     $('#optionTwo').attr("checked",false);
 });

 $("#send-decide").click(function() {
  if($('#optionTwo').is(':checked')){
   $('.decider ').addClass('hide');
   $('.box-one').removeClass('hide');
  }
  if($('#optionOne').is(':checked')){
   $('.decider ').addClass('hide');
   $('.box-two').removeClass('hide');
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<div class="decider hide">
  <p style="font-size:10px;color:#000;">Please select an option below</p>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input id="optionTwo" type="checkbox" name="Request" value="Request" />
    Select Box one </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input id="optionOne" type="checkbox" name="Download" value="Download" />
    Select Box two </label>
  <br />
  <span class="select"> 
    <input type="button" id="send-decide" alt="submit" value="select" />
  </span> </div>
  
<div class="box-one">
  <p>this is first box</p>
</div>

<div class="box-two hide">
  <p>this is second box</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try setting the CSS attribute `display: block` and `display: none`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `.hide` class `display:none` property css.. Rest everything is fine

```js
$(function() {
 $('.decider').removeClass('hide');
 $('.box-one,.box-two').addClass('hide');//add hide to both the class
    
 $("#optionTwo").click(function() {
     $('#optionOne').attr("checked",false);
 });

 $("#optionOne").click(function() {
     $('#optionTwo').attr("checked",false);
 });

 $("#send-decide").click(function() {
        if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length)//check whether any checkbox is checked
        {
            //if yes go ahead and do what you wanted to do
            $('.decider ').addClass('hide'); //hide it in any case
            if($('#optionTwo').is(':checked')){
                $('.box-one').removeClass('hide');
            }
            if($('#optionOne').is(':checked')){
                $('.box-two').removeClass('hide');
            }
        }
        else
          alert('select a checkbox');//if not display some message to user
 });
});
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none; //add this property
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="decider hide">
  <p style="font-size:10px;color:#000;">Please select an option below</p>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input id="optionTwo" type="checkbox" name="Request" value="Request" />
    Select Box one </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input id="optionOne" type="checkbox" name="Download" value="Download" />
    Select Box two </label>
  <br />
  <span class="select"> 
    <input type="button" id="send-decide" alt="submit" value="select" />
  </span> </div>
  
<div class="box-one">
  <p>this is first box</p>
</div>

<div class="box-two">
  <p>this is second box</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @user2281289 if you give me proper scenario I can give you more optimized solution!! Bdw I've edited answer.. If this is fine then happy coding to you.. :)